# How do I create a dynamic endorsement policy (ESCC) in Hyperledger Fabric 1.2?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Under endorsement policies documentation, the following is stated:

> Dynamic addition of endorsement policies (e.g., by deploy transaction on chaincode deploy time) is very sensitive in terms of bounded policy evaluation time (termination), determinism, performance and security guarantees. Therefore, dynamic addition of endorsement policies is not allowed, but can be supported in future.

**If I'm interested in having a more fluid endorsement policy whereby we're constantly adding new peers and would like the endorsement policy to be based on a unique set of peers which correlate to specific transactions, would that be possible?**

I.e. in some cases a transaction is between two specific peers, so they should both be valid endorsers. Five other peers exist, lets say they're *competitors*, and they should not be allowed to endorse in that scenario.

In 1.1, it doesn't appear as though you can deploy your own custom ESCC/VSCC as mentioned in https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-8729.

With the new 1.2 pluggable architecture, I don't see how I could obtain access to the `ChaincodeStubInterface` to handle custom logic based on passed transaction params. For example, the old 1.1 pluggable chaincode architecture extended `Chaincode interface`.

Given the method signatures below, **is it possible to gain access to the `ChaincodeStubInterface` with the data from the new method signatures?**

https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/pluggable_endorsement_and_validation.html

`Endorse(payload []byte, sp *peer.SignedProposal) (*peer.Endorsement, []byte, error)`

`Validate(block *common.Block, namespace string, txPosition int, actionPosition int, contextData ...ContextDatum) error`

Specifically, I want access to something like `args := stub.GetStringArgs()` or even just the payload's composite key / index name.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to develop the similar feature on my own apps recently. Though dynamic endorsement policy is not supported in the current version, we can using dynamic configuration to help us define what endorsement method we expected in our apps.

I am not sure whether we can directly access to the `ChaincodeStubInterface` with the method signatures, but I will try it and keep updating.

Here is my solution. Hope this can help.

1. Using [Fabric-SDK-Node](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node) to create my apps, and make sure the fabric version is above 1.1.0, which provide a more comprehensive configuration file for us.
2. Here is part of sample configuration file, provided by official:

   ```
   orderers:
     - orderer.example.com
   peers:
     peer0.org1.example.com:
       endorsingPeer: true
       chaincodeQuery: true
       ledgerQuery: true
       eventSource: true
     peer0.org2.example.com:
       endorsingPeer: true
       chaincodeQuery: true
       ledgerQuery: true
       eventSource: true
   chaincodes:
     - mycc:v0
   ```
3. You can notice that this sample provide four option for us to define which connection policy that you want to use for your transaction. By setting `peer0.org2.endorsingPeer` as `false`, when a situation, which someone send a invoke proposal to the fabric network, happens after the user finished `setConfigSetting` and loaded the connection profile, the transaction can only be endorsed by peer0.org1. The rest of the three option works the same as the `endorsingPeer`.
4. Now that we can create a function to let user dynamic design their desired endorsement policy before sending a transaction.